# JQuery popup model for videos

Tags: jquery, youtube-javascript-api

I am new to JQuery and am trying to display a YouTube playlist in thumbnails and if the user clicks a thumbnail, the video will play in a modal popup.  I've found some code that retrieves a youtube playlist based on a playlist ID and it works great:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Vidz</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8F9409C187634853?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
        var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
        $.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
            var list_data = "";
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
                var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
                var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
                var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
                var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
                var url = videoURL + videoID;
                var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";
                list_data += '<li><a href="' + url + '" title="' + feedTitle + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"></a></li>';                
            });
            $(list_data).appendTo(".cont");
        });
    });//]]>  

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="cont"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I've found endless JQuery popup examples but the problem is they are all using a different version of JQuery than this example uses, so they cancel each other other and the modal popup doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how I can make a modal popup with the video that the user clicks on?

UPDATE:
Finally found something that solved the JQuery conflict issue.  It seems that jquery.min.js needs to be loaded first, before any other jquery script.  That resolved most of the issues but a new issue arose;  Links display as needed and such but when I click on them, nothing happens.  I decided to use the F12 feature in IE9 and look at the HTML that was being generated....all looks good, but here's where it gets weird.....if I View Source on my page, I get the same code as above.  If I use F12 and view it, I see all the html tags.  When I save the contents of F12 to a new file and open it in IE, it works!  So, what's the difference?  Is IE not writing out the html needed?  Totally lost now.....

UPDATE #2:
Here's my latest code with the jquery modal popup in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Vidz</title>
</head>
<body>
<a title="01212012 Country Ham House rally" class="youtube" href="#" rel="vLZ5pIfrhNI">ham</a><br />
<div class="cont"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function () {
    var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8F9409C187634853?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
    var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    $.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
        var list_data = "";
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
            var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
            var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
            var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
            var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
            var url = videoURL + videoID;
            var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";
            //list_data += '<li><a href="' + url + '" title="' + feedTitle + '" rel="' + videoID + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"</a></li>';                
            list_data += '<a class="youtube" href="#" rel="' + videoID + '" title="' + feedTitle + '"><img alt="' + feedTitle + '" src="' + thumb + '"></a><br>';
        });
        $(list_data).appendTo(".cont");
    });
});//]]>
</script>
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />     
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://wo.simcare.biz/jquery.youtubepopup.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { $("a.youtube").YouTubePopup({ autoplay: 0 }); });     
</script>
```

As you can see with the static link "ham", the vid displays in the popup just fine.  But none of the videos with thumbnails (created by jquery function) work.

Thoughts???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug tools read whats on the browser in realtime. The source is the code before it hits the browser. JavaScript manipulates your content within the browser, not the source.

Also your links seem to work fine in IE9
http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/guMQa/2/

Comment: yeah, I used fiddle to debug and help me out with this also....great little tool.  My issue is i've added some code to show a jquery modal pop-up...but when I click the vid, nothing happens.  it almost appears as if the page hasn't rendered the HTML fully or something like that....If I take the pop-up code and supply a static link (the "a" tag with a specific class and url), it works fine.  When I try to build that same link in my jquery above, it doesn't work.  The link appears just fine according to F12 but it's just not working.  Frustrating for sure.....

Comment: Strange, in my IE9 the source code you provided work perfectly when JavaScript generates the links. The anchor link works as intended. Try your code in an alternative browser.

Comment: Updated the code above, works now. You're binding an event to <a> tags that dont exist. After the JSON is loaded and appends the new <a> tags _then_ you bind the event.

Comment: Can you show me what you've changed?  My head is spinning ATM and I've got tunnel vision and can't see it for some reason.

Comment: Go to this link http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/guMQa/2/ I've also updated the post link (it didnt update on the page so it was still showing the old code, sorry!)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6934/discussion-between-robert-and-matt-lo)

Comment: Matt, you are a life saver.  I see the changes you've made and now understand why it wasn't working.  Unreal how the smallest things can become so consuming sometimes. I've been working on this for 5 hours last night and 4+ tonight...THANKS again...